# Access service in remote Kubernetes cluster using ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I'm attempting to access a service in an existing kubernetes cluster deployed in a remote machine. I've configured the cluster to be accessible through `kubectl` from my local mac.

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.58.114:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.58.114:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

The ingress configuration for the service I want to connect is:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: gw-ingress
  namespace: vick-system
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/vick-system/ingresses/gw-ingress
  uid: 52b62da6-01c1-11e9-9f59-fa163eb296d8
  resourceVersion: '2695'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2018-12-17T06:02:23Z'
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity":"cookie","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash":"sha1","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name":"route"},"name":"gw-ingress","namespace":"vick-system"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"wso2-apim-gateway","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"gateway","servicePort":8280},"path":"/"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["wso2-apim-gateway"]}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - wso2-apim-gateway
  rules:
    - host: wso2-apim-gateway
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: gateway
              servicePort: 8280
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 172.17.17.100
```

My list of services are:
[image]

My `/etc/hosts` file looks like below:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

172.17.17.100 wso2-apim-gateway wso2-apim wso2sp-dashboard
```

What is the URL I should use to access this service from my local browser? Should I do any more configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https://wso2-apim-gateway/` is the URL that will point to the `gateway` service according to your configuration. This is defined by the `host: wso2-apim-gateway` part of your configuration. Note that your load balancer (`172.17.17.100`) is a private IP address, so you will need to be on the same network to access it.

I can't see any further configuration required, except perhaps TLS certifications - if you receive a 5xx response, you may want to check the logs of the ingress-nginx deployment/replicaset.

Comment: Yes. The problem was with the external IP of the nodeport I was using. I edited it to the actual IP of the remote host it was running and also replaced the entry in /etc/hosts with that IP and things worked well.